# Range, Domain, Inverse of a Function

Tags: functions

Define a function on the real numbers by:

$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$

and calculate the following:

$\text{Dom }f=(-\infty, 1)\cup(1,\infty)$

$\text{Range }f=\text{Dom }f^{-1}=(-\infty,1)\cup(1,\infty)$.

Inverse=$\frac{x+1}{x-1}$

Do my answers look correct?

Also, is it true that $f\circ \!\,f^{-1}=f^{-1} \circ \!\, f=(x,f(x))$?

Comment: Observe that $f$ is not defined a $x=1$, the domain is not equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa so i would say all real numbers except x=1?

Comment: Yes, $D=\mathbb{R}-\left\{1\right\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have calculated $f^{-1}$ correctly. Now,

$\text{Dom }f=(-\infty, 1)\cup(1,\infty)$

$\text{Range }f=\text{Dom }f^{-1}=(-\infty,1)\cup(1,\infty)$.